# How to calculate mountain front sinuosity index using DEM?

Tags: geology, geomorphology, tectonics

In tectonic geomorphology the Mountain front sinuosity index is one of the morphometric indexes.

Smf = Lmf/Ls

I have a DEM, so how do I use it to find the value?

[image]

According to this diagram do I have to digitize all the mountain front?

Comment: Question, because I am not an expert, how are these values calculated ? Could be as simple as choosing a contour line and then (length of the arc)/(length of chord connecting endpoints). In which case the question is already answered with Smf=Lmf/Ls ...

Comment: I tried using contour but in the above image the lines are not generated using contours.